# Facebook application framework

Tags: php, asp.net, facebook

I am new to facebook application.
I am a ASP.NET developer but also have knowledge of PHP.
I just want to know if i have to choose facebook application API/framework, which one i should choose ASP.NET or PHP.
One of my friend suggest that Facebook itself build in PHP and they officially support PHP API, so use PHP facebook application API/framework.

Please suggest!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with .Net, you can try use the [Microsoft's facebook SDK](http://www.codeplex.com/FacebookToolkit).

[This](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Facebook%20application%20development%20in%20ASP.NET&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is a nice & easy (and basic) step-by-step guide.

Comment: Thanks sagie for your answer, but i can choose any one. I want to choose best one.